# How do I create an SQL trigger that updates on one table after an activity on another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create schema tr_sp_lab;

use tr_sp_lab;

create table Account (
ACC_NUM varchar(8) not null,
ACC_TYPE char(2) not null,
CUS_NAME varchar(45),
BALANCE decimal(10,2),
constraint Account_pk primary key(ACC_NUM)
);

create table Transactions (
TRANS_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ACC_NUM varchar(8) not null,
AMOUNT decimal(10,2),
TRANS_TYPE char(1),
constraint Transactions_fk foreign key(ACC_NUM) references Account(ACC_NUM)
);

create table DELETED_ACCOUNTS (
ACC_NUM varchar(8) not null,
ACC_TYPE char(2) not null,
CUS_NAME varchar(45),
BALANCE decimal(10,2),
CLOSED_DATE datetime,
constraint Deleted_Accounts_pk primary key(ACC_NUM)
);

INSERT INTO ACCOUNT VALUES
('A1', 'SA', 'Alex', 1000.0),
('A2', 'SA', 'Bob', 500.0),
('A3', 'FD', 'Alex', 3000.0),
('A4', 'SA', 'Cathy', 750.0),
('A5', 'SA', 'Daniel', 600.0),
('A6', 'FD', 'Cathy', 2000.0),
('A7', 'FD', 'Eagan', 1000.0),
('A8', 'SA', 'Eagan', 500.0),
('A9', 'SA', 'Alex', 550.0);

INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS(ACC_NUM, AMOUNT, TRANS_TYPE) VALUES
('A1', 1000.0, 'D'),
('A2', 500.0, 'D'),
('A3', 1000.0, 'D'),
('A3', 1000.0, 'D'),
('A3', 1000.0, 'D'),
('A4', 500.0, 'D'),
('A4', 500.0, 'D'),
('A4', 250.0, 'W'),
('A5', 600.0, 'D'),
('A6', 1000.0, 'D'),
('A6', 500.0, 'D'),
('A6', 500.0, 'D'),
('A7', 1000.0, 'D'),
('A8', 500.0, 'D'),
('A9', 550.0, 'D');

#Attempted trigger code below

DELIMITER $$
create trigger account_update
after insert on transactions
for each row
begin
    if trans_type='W' then
        insert into account values(
        new.acc_num, new.acc_type, new.cus_name, new.balance - amount
        );
     elseif trans_type='D' then
        insert into account values(
        new.acc_num, new.acc_type, new.cus_name, new.balance + amount
        );
    end if;
end $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Hi so I want to create a trigger that fires when a customer makes a transaction i.e. deposits or withdraws amount represented by 'D' and 'W' in TRANS_TYPE in the transaction table. The trigger should update the balance column for the corresponding account.

When an amount is deposited into an account, the balance of the corresponding account
number should increase by that amount in the Account table.

Similarly, when an amount is withdrawn, the balance of the corresponding account number
should decrease by the withdrawal amount.

Thanks!

Comment: Stop and don't. Instead drop the `balance` column all together. Materializing such a value which is to be calculated by other data -- summing the transactions -- is redundant and can lead to inconsistencies. You can always query the *right* balance. For convenience you can create a view that does that, so that you don't have to repeat the query every time.

Comment: But as a hint: `INSERT` creates new rows. If you want to change rows, use `UPDATE`.

Comment: But it's a school assignment. Anyhow, I think I solved it

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger account_update
after insert on transactions
for each row
begin

    declare curr_balance decimal(10,2);
    select balance INTO curr_balance from account where acc_num=new.acc_num;

    if new.trans_type='W' then
        update account set balance = curr_balance - new.amount where acc_num=new.acc_num;
    elseif new.trans_type='D' then
        update account set balance = curr_balance + new.amount where acc_num=new.acc_num;

    end if;
end $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here's my answer to my question